# Airflow Datadog hook conn_id format

Tags: python, airflow, hook, datadog

I want to use a [DatadogHook](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.8/_api/airflow/contrib/hooks/datadog_hook/index.html) in one of my Airflow DAGs. As documentation says, I need to pass a `datadog_conn_id` upon hook initialization, and the parameter description says:

```
datadog_conn_id – The connection to datadog, containing metadata for api keys.
datadog_conn_id – str
```

The problem is that I couldn't figure out what the format of `datadog_conn_id` should be. It's not exactly specified in the documentation. After digging in some of Airflow source code, I [found](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/providers/datadog/hooks/datadog.py#L42) out that it expects to find `api_key` and `app_key` from the given `datadog_conn_id`, but not sure how does it extract them from the given string, what's the expected format.

So, is there any well known format that is meant here that I don't know? I don't believe that documentation is just missing such an important information.

**Note**: I do have both API and APP keys ready, just not sure about the format in which I should provide them to the hook.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define them as Json in the extra feild.

```
{"app_key": "appkey", "api_key": "apikey"}
```

A good source for this information would be to look on the hook [unit tests](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/d411f4604bc0c36c7e5b6f7b6cc3cca9798d7c15/tests/providers/datadog/hooks/test_datadog.py#L51:L58).